# 'Follow' or 'Mention' Twitter button to allow feedback?

Tags: twitter

I have just created a Twitter account to let people provide feedback from a web page offering a small service. I am no expert at Twitter. I see that several buttons are [available](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#mention). I want to add such a button on my page.

I am hesitating between `mention` and `hashtag`. Basically, I want users to be able to post a comment on our account.

Is that possible?
What would be the best choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `mention` the tweet starts with `@yourname` which means that only people that are following both you and that account will see it in their timeline.

If you do a `hashtag` you won't have the above problem, but you will have to deal with the search history limitation that Twitter's hashtag search creates (anywhere from 5-10 days of history only).

Users won't be able to post a comment on your account because Twitter doesn't work like that (there's no `page` to leave a post on).

I would suggest the `mention` option because then you can go back and find them easier, you can get notifications when someone does mention you, and if their friends do see the tweet they can easily find your account.